# Does TFS 2010 support Optimistic locking?

Tags: tfs

Does anyone know that whether TFS 2010 support optimistic locking or only pessimistic locking?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, TFS 2010 supports optimistic locking.  Files are not exclusively locked; multiple users can have the same file checked out simultaneously.  Conflicts are resolved through merging files upon check-in.

However, if the file is "non-mergable" (images, audio, etc), it will be exclusively locked.

Comment: thanks a lot man! It's the answer that I was looking for. One more question, are there any options provided to merger changes?

Comment: When merging conflicts, you have the option to take the server version, keep the local version, auto-merge, or merge in the diff tool.